# search a value from an array based on another array

Tags: php

i have two arrays $schoolteachers and $schoolgroups...

> $schoolgroups=Array ( 
>             [0] = Array
>           ( 
>    [groupid] = 1
>               [groupname] =Red
>               [members] = Array
>                   (
>                       [0] = Array
>                           (
>                               [id] = 13
>                               [name] = Sooraj 
>                           )
>
> ```
>                 [1] = Array
>                     (
>                         [id] = 12
>                         [name] = sanjay
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [1] =&gt; Array
>     (
>         [groupid] = 2
>         [groupname] = Blue
>         [members] = Array
>             (
>                 [0] = Array
>                     (
>                         [id] = 9
>                         [name] = Anith
>                     )
>
>                 [1] = Array
>                     (
>                         [id] = 4
>                         [name] = John
>                     )
>
>             );
> ```

$schoolteachers=Array (

> ```
> [0] =&gt; Array
>     (
>         [employee_id] = 7
>         [emp_name] = Anantha Raman
>     )
>
> [1] =&gt; Array
>     (
>         [employee_id] =&gt; 9
>         [emp_name] = Anith
>     )
>
> [2] = Array
>     (
>         [employee_id] = 11
>         [emp_name] = Aravind
>     ) });
> ```

i want to check $schoolteachers 'empname',is in schoolgroup array($schoolgroup ['members'][''name]=Aravind)  and echo only non members
i want to display name based  $schoolteachers array if it is not present in $schoolgroups

I used the code it's not fine

```
foreach ($schoolteachers as $teachers) {
    $classin = false;
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($schoolgroups)) as $value) {
        if ($value == $teachers['emp_name']) {

            $classin = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$classin) {
        echo $teachers['emp_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have structure of your array .... and sample expected output

Comment: hi i add the array to my question

Comment: What is your expected Result ?? Did you test the code below ?

Comment: i want to echo employe names(ie,Anantha Raman
,Aravind) from the array schoolteachers here Anith is exists in schoolgroups  therefor it don't echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$names = array_map(function($v){ return $v['emp_name']; }, $schoolteachers);
$members = array();
array_walk_recursive($schoolgroups, function($item,$key) use (&$members) {
    $key === "name" and $members[] = $item ;
});

echo "<pre>";
foreach($names as $name)
{
    if(!in_array($name, $members))
        echo $name,PHP_EOL;

}
```

Output

```
Anantha Raman
Aravind
```

[See Full Demo](http://eval.in/4346)